# Java MVC project in Spring Tool Suite additional files

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-tool-suite

I'm learning to make Java MVC project using Spring Tool Suite tool.
The path to make new project is:
File->New->SpringLegacyProject->Spring MVC Project.

My question is: which directory I have to use to add additional not-Spring files and where and what do I have to type for Spring files to see them?

For example:

- css files - where to put and how to make jsp views see them, will   'link rel="" 'tag be enough?
- properties files used to specify database connection or to specify messages for ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource. In this case, do I have to create bean for this class in root-context.xml?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use Spring Boot (i.e. use File->New->Spring Starter Project and select `Web` as a starter. Place your web resources under `src/main/resources/static` folder. They are picked up automatically from that folder.
You should try an example project: File -> New -> Import Spring Getting Started Content and then pick "Serving Web Content" from the list.
Try some DB getting started content example to get the answer for the second part of your question.